# How to Open multiple text/JSON file and same is to be converted in one excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to import only one JSON file on the basis of following code How to import multiple JSON files at a same time?

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim jsonText As String
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream

myfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="JSON file (*.json), *.json")

If myfile <> False Then 

    Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile(myfile, ForReading)
    jsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
    JsonTS.Close

Else

    MsgBox ("File not Selected")
    Exit Sub

End If

Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want the user to be able to select multiple file (please be clearer in your questions next time).

If so, work further from here:

```
filespec = Application.GetOpenFileName(FileFilter:="JSON file (*.json), *.json", Title:="Get File", MultiSelect:=True)

For i = 1 To UBound(filespec)
   ' Better put the contents of this For Loop in a separate Sub
   Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile(filespec(i), ForReading)
   jsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
   JsonTS.Close
   Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)
   .....
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks @Roemer but i am not able to open all file in one go after adding your code also. Please suggest

Comment: I am at a complete loss at what you want, what the results are that you want, what the results are that you are getting. You will have to be more precise. It is also the reason that noone else is reacting.

Comment: Sir i want a code on which we can select & convert multiple JSON to excel based upon above code provided by me.

Comment: Well I gave you that. The key is in the multiselect:=true parameter. Check if your version of excel supports it, maybe you have an old version. It absolutely works in Excel 2013. So not much more I can do for you. Unless you are very specific on what goes wrong at exactly what moment, error messages, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Roemer, When I put your code and select multi JSON afterwards every data JSON is start from First row. I want that every data should be start from that row where previous JSON is completed.

Comment: I am sorry Nandan. But I still have no clue what you are talking about. You seem to bring up a completely new question here? (If so, create a new question!)  Do the JSON's have similar rows? How are they structured? What are you trying to achieve EXACTLY (details!). It all is a blank. I cannot see your code, I cannot read your mind. PLEASE read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask